# Cannot import comma delimited quoted file in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, libreoffice

I am trying to import this data to `Pandas`. It imports correctly in Libreoffice with a header and 2 lines. However, in `Pandas`, it does not seem to import. There are some newline characters inside that should be ignored. But in Pandas, they are being treated as a new line instead of single field with `\n` inside it. Has anyone faced such issue. I've tried setting `quotechar` and `sep` parameters in `Pandas` but cannot import it.

Thanks in advance

[data is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mex5h61n4nbhexn/data_to_post.csv?dl=0)

This should be imported as 2 rows in Pandas. However, it is being split into multiple rows.

[image: Output in pandas is this]

Comment: Open it with a text editor (Notepad or something), and see what's the delimiter for the rows. What error are you getting?

Comment: provide some sample data and code.

Comment: your data has ',' in between data as well so panda's can not read it properly. you need to change your sap when you are creating this csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have `"` as escape char (`\"`) in your text that panda should ignore.

e.g.

> 7/20/16:  Decreased STS, active flexion to 130, abduction to 100, weak right handed grip. Lack 6-8 **\"** IR on right, only to waist.

The \" after Lack 6-8 shouldn't be interpreted as quote character.

You have to tell pandas that.

That should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("resources/data_to_post.csv", quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
print(df)
```

## Output

```
   id  ...                                      PlanGenerated
0   1  ...  A course of physical therapy was ordered. Mobi...
1   2  ...  The patient is instructed to return if pain or...

[2 rows x 17 columns]
```

only two rows then 6 as before.

Comment: Thanks...also can you have a look at last line 4. That seems strange

Comment: what you mean with last line 4? and what with strange? @prms

Comment: That line does not have escape chars and data seems fine. To import that error_bad_lines needs to be set to False and other lines are split into multiple. I added that line later

Comment: I see... you have inconsistency in your data. In the new line you have "out". Now he interpret this " as quote character even if they don't meant to be quote characters... that leads to this unexpected behaviour. If you would change this to \" or remove " then it would work. @prms

Comment: @prms if you change "out" to \"out\" it should be fixed. In case you load other data that have the same issue ofc it will break as well. The problem is inconsistency and I think you may only fix it if you preprocess the data. Don't think pandas can handle that.